# How to avoid Bootstrap 4 NavBar from expanding when implementing an autocomplete field in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use React 16.5.2 and Bootstrap 4.1.3 on my project and I want to have a typeahead on a NavBar. I have implemented the autocomplete field on the NavBar but it did not turn out the way I want it. 
It seems that when the list of suggestion came out it will expand the NavBar too.
Another problem is the list of suggestion is on the right side of the input text instead of on the left side. For your information, I'm a React newbie and I'm using react-places-autocomplete to get the list of suggestion.
Most of the typeahead that I found is used outside of Navbar.
Here is the image of the NavBar with the autocomplete field.

[image]

Here are some packages that I use:-

1. React Places Autocomplete - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-places-autocomplete.
2. bootstrap 4.1.3 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap
3. Create React App - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Below is a snippet of the code from my SearchForm component:-

```
   render() {
    return (
        <form className="mx-2 my-auto d-inline w-100" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            {this.state.gmapsLoaded && (
                <PlacesAutocomplete
                    value={this.state.address}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    onSelect={this.handleSelect}
                >
                    {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (

                        <div className="input-group">
                            <input
                                {...getInputProps({
                                    placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                                    className: 'form-control border border--0',
                                })}
                            />
                            <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
                                {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                                {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                                    const className = suggestion.active
                                        ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                                        : 'suggestion-item';
                                    // inline style for demonstration purpose
                                    const style = suggestion.active
                                        ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                                        : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                                    return (
                                        <div
                                            {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                                                className,
                                                style,
                                            })}
                                        >
                                            <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <span className="input-group-append">
                                <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary border border-left-0" type="button" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </PlacesAutocomplete>
            )}
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: Need more details about packages which you are  using, Please mention **auto complete**  component package name.

Comment: @Balaji731 : Here are some packages that I use; 1) React Places Autocomplete - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-places-autocomplete.
2) bootstrap 4.1.3 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap
3) Create React App - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app